# How can I log onto the IRS website without using ID.me?

Tags: income-tax, irs, stimulus, online

Several years ago when I went to log into my online IRS account they had added **ID.me** to their site and I have been trying ever since to get verified. I have many of the secondary documents proving my identity however, I don't have an unexpired by less than a year driver's license. I can't even make a video call until I upload a picture ID which I don't have since my driver's license expired a couple of years ago. I have stimulus payments that I would love to receive and I need to log into my account for other things as well. Is there a workaround **ID.me**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can no longer log in to your IRS account without using Id.Me. As unfortunate as it is, you must use the private third party system to use the government portal.

Comment: Are there brick-and-mortar IRS offices? It takes forever to call them and then they don't help you once you do get a person on the phone.

Comment: @DC_Lady https://apps.irs.gov/app/office-locator/

Comment: Medicare , and some of the other government services I've looked at in the past year or two, still do have alternatives to id.me. But, yeah, looks as if the IRS hasn't yet been convinced to do so. At least so far id.me has seemed reasonably secure...